# How to find the right rust nightly version when build substrate project from github

Tags: substrate

I pulled some open-source substrate projects from Github.
I got many errors of API in crates. I think it was caused by version mismatching of Rust.
How can I know which version should I choose when running these commands?

```
rustup install nightly-<YYYY-MM-DD>
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-<YYYY-MM-DD>
rustup default nightly-<YYYY-MM-DD>
```

Suppose that I found the right version nightly-2021-10-20, is there a case it works on macOS, but not in Windows?

Comment: You can find the version in some files: shell.nix, init.sh, build.sh ... in your source code folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose that I found the right version nightly-2021-10-20, is there a
> case it works on macOS, but not in Windows?

No it is independent of OS. If it is working on Mac, it will work on Linux and Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

To determine this shell.nix file is present at substrate [repo](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/shell.nix)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pulled project is created a long time ago, the substrate repo is updated regularly,
is the current version ok?